# Webpack middleware stopped watching for file-changes

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-hmr, webpack-hot-middleware

I used `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware` for months and it was working just FINE, but now, something happened and webpack stopeed watching for file changes so bundle rebuilds only when i restart the app. What could happen? I'm on arch linux with `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288` setting on and with `:set backupcopy=yes` vim option tuned as well.
What could happen? How to get things back?

The initial bundling happen, middleware loads properly as i see in logs. Here are lines loading webpack middlewares in entry app.

```
(function() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    console.server('Running webpack middleware...');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var webpackConfig = require('../config/webpack.config.js');
    var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

    app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
      hot: true,
      noInfo: false,
      stats: {
        colors: true
      },
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '',
      contentBase: './app'
    }));

    app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler, {
      log: console.webpack,
      heartbeat: 10 * 1000
    }));
  }
})();
```

and `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const PATHS = {
  app: {
    client: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app'),
    admin: path.resolve(__dirname, '../admin-app')
  },
  styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/stylesheets'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/build'),
  public: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')
};

const plugins = [
  // Shared code
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
  // Avoid publishing files when compilation fails
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'false'))
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheet.css')
];

const config = {
  env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    client: [path.resolve(PATHS.app.client + '/index.js'), 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr'],
    admin: [path.resolve(PATHS.app.admin + '/index.js'), 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr']
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    alias: {},
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: PATHS.app.client,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: PATHS.app.admin,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  devtool: 'eval'
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lol just a stupid typo in `console.webpack` function which passed to `webpack-hot-middleware log` didn't let it work. Saw Error when scrolled to the very top of huge log outpt provided by webpack, and that made this typo so stealthy.